# Could not find or load main class when running Java after a project is built using {mvn clean package}

Tags: java, maven, jar

It is an IBM MQ challenge and I have applied the provided instructions, however, I faced the ClassNotFound exception after the project is built using maven.

I noticed the following line in the result of `mvn clean package` command

[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>TicketGenerator</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>

  <name>mq-dev-badge-sample</name>
  <url>https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-badge-sample</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
        <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.ibm.mq.badge.Manager</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <filters>
                  <filter>
                      <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                      <excludes>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                          <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                      </excludes>
                  </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Result of mvn clean package:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.ibm.mq:TicketGenerator >---------------------
[INFO] Building mq-dev-badge-sample 1.4
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ TicketGenerator ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\MQClient\mq-dev-badge-sample-master\MQTicketService\TicketGenerator\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ TicketGenerator ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\MQClient\mq-dev-badge-sample-master\MQTicketService\TicketGenerator\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ TicketGenerator ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ TicketGenerator ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\MQClient\mq-dev-badge-sample-master\MQTicketService\TicketGenerator\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ TicketGenerator ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ TicketGenerator ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ TicketGenerator ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: E:\MQClient\mq-dev-badge-sample-master\MQTicketService\TicketGenerator\target\TicketGenerator-1.4.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) @ TicketGenerator ---
[INFO] Including com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:jar:9.3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:jar:1.71 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15to18:jar:1.71 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15to18:jar:1.71 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.json:json:jar:20220320 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:2.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:4.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation.
[WARNING] TicketGenerator-1.4.jar, bcpkix-jdk15to18-1.71.jar, bcprov-jdk15to18-1.71.jar, bcutil-jdk15to18-1.71.jar, com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.0.0.jar, istack-commons-runtime-4.0.1.jar, jakarta.activation-2.0.0.jar, jakarta.activation-api-2.0.1.jar, jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.0.jar, javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar, jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar, jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar, jaxb-impl-3.0.0.jar, json-20220320.jar, txw2-3.0.0.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[WARNING] istack-commons-runtime-4.0.1.jar, jakarta.activation-2.0.0.jar, jakarta.activation-api-2.0.1.jar, jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.0.jar, jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar, jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar, jaxb-impl-3.0.0.jar, txw2-3.0.0.jar define 2 overlapping resources:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/LICENSE.md
[WARNING]   - META-INF/NOTICE.md
[WARNING] jakarta.activation-2.0.0.jar, jakarta.activation-api-2.0.1.jar define 31 overlapping classes:
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.ActivationDataFlavor
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.CommandInfo
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.CommandInfo$Beans
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.CommandInfo$Beans$1
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.CommandMap
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.CommandObject
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.DataHandler
[WARNING]   - jakarta.activation.DataHandler$1
[WARNING]   - 21 more...
[WARNING] jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar, jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar define 128 overlapping classes and resources:
[WARNING]   - META-INF.versions.9.org.glassfish.jaxb.core.StackHelper
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - org.glassfish.jaxb.core.Locatable
[WARNING]   - org.glassfish.jaxb.core.StackHelper
[WARNING]   - org.glassfish.jaxb.core.Utils
[WARNING]   - org.glassfish.jaxb.core.WhiteSpaceProcessor
[WARNING]   - org.glassfish.jaxb.core.annotation.OverrideAnnotationOf
[WARNING]   - org.glassfish.jaxb.core.annotation.XmlIsSet
[WARNING]   - org.glassfish.jaxb.core.annotation.XmlLocation
[WARNING]   - 118 more...
[WARNING] jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar, txw2-3.0.0.jar define 55 overlapping classes and resources:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - com.sun.xml.txw2.Attribute
[WARNING]   - com.sun.xml.txw2.Cdata
[WARNING]   - com.sun.xml.txw2.Comment
[WARNING]   - com.sun.xml.txw2.ContainerElement
[WARNING]   - com.sun.xml.txw2.Content
[WARNING]   - com.sun.xml.txw2.ContentVisitor
[WARNING]   - com.sun.xml.txw2.DatatypeWriter
[WARNING]   - com.sun.xml.txw2.DatatypeWriter$1
[WARNING]   - 45 more...
[WARNING] istack-commons-runtime-4.0.1.jar, jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar define 25 overlapping classes and resources:
[WARNING]   - META-INF.versions.9.com.sun.istack.logging.StackHelper
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime/pom.properties
[WARNING]   - META-INF/maven/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime/pom.xml
[WARNING]   - com.sun.istack.Builder
[WARNING]   - com.sun.istack.ByteArrayDataSource
[WARNING]   - com.sun.istack.FinalArrayList
[WARNING]   - com.sun.istack.FragmentContentHandler
[WARNING]   - com.sun.istack.Interned
[WARNING]   - com.sun.istack.NotNull
[WARNING]   - com.sun.istack.Nullable
[WARNING]   - 15 more...
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing E:\MQClient\mq-dev-badge-sample-master\MQTicketService\TicketGenerator\target\TicketGenerator-1.4.jar with E:\MQClient\mq-dev-badge-sample-master\MQTicketService\TicketGenerator\target\TicketGenerator-1.4-shaded.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: E:\MQClient\mq-dev-badge-sample-master\MQTicketService\TicketGenerator\dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.547 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-12T00:20:42+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result of IBM Instructed `java -cp target\TicketGenerator-1.4.jar; com.ibm.mq.badge.Manager`

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ibm.mq.badge.Manager
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.badge.Manager
```

Please advise folks

Comment: Looks like you don’t have any source files under `src/java/main` which is where maven looks for them.

Comment: This `[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date` shows that there are no source files as @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen already mentioned.

Comment: The [TicketGenerator](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-badge-sample/tree/master/MQTicketService/TicketGenerator/src/main/java) project just consists of two symbolic links which point to a parent directory: `../../../com/`. Did you checkout the entire github repository and leave the folder structure untouched? The link is supposed to point to [this directory](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-badge-sample/tree/master/MQTicketService/TicketGenerator/com/ibm/mq) it looks like...very weird project structure!

Comment: @slindenau As you mentioned I kept everything untouched, I just copied the project and run maven to build the app, for me this is the first time to see this structure in maven projects

Comment: Are you on windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: @chughts I'm on windows

Comment: Are you free to move the files around? I would just move the `com` folder to the expected location for a maven project and get rid of the symbolic links (if that doesn't break anything else for that project).

Comment: @slindenau actually I'm not good with maven projects and there should be some modifications on POM file and I dont have any idea what exactly to be changed

Comment: @slindenau yes your suggestion has worked! I removed the link files and moved the com folder into src/main/java and run mvn and the JAR file is build successfully and java application worked fine.

Comment: @slindenau sounds like someone who mavenized an existing project but didn’t want to move files so just threw in a few symlinks. Could be to ensure version control history.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @slindenau,  I removed the link files and moved the com folder into src/main/java and run mvn and the JAR file is build successfully and java application worked fine.